# Showing Recent Messages Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPointerShape

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-maps-sdk-ios

**While running this error is occurred, I tried reinstall pod and delete derived data and clean and run, but no use, please give me a solution to resolve this, Thanks in advance**

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITTtd.png**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trouble with some pod issue, if you sure you updated to pod and deleted derived data then:

[image]

or Update Xcode and try again

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried above solutions but issue still exist.

Comment: Thanks for your response and time, it's fixed by updating Xcode